# Avoiding repetition with concepts

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

When writing overloads for r-value I often end up with the same code. So to avoid repetition I use this trick

```
void f(int&&) {
    std::println("&& overload");
}
void f(int const&) {
    std::println("const& overload");
}

template<typename T1, typename T2>
concept no_repetition = std::same_as<std::remove_cvref_t<T1>, T2>;

void test(no_repetition<int> auto&& val) {
    f(std::forward<decltype(val)>(val));
}

int main( ) {
    int lval = 0;
    test(0);    //prints && overload
    test(lval); //prints const& overload
    return 0;
}
```

I am curious whether this approach has caveats. And if it does how can work around them.

Comment: What repetition do you mean?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Like in my example I would have to write 2 overloads for test(). One for r-value reference and the other for l-value. And in the real code the body of the function is a little bit bigger also I have to write this kind of code multiple times, so I end up with a lot of repetition.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to solve, but this works just as well: https://godbolt.org/z/496Y8GWfd

Comment: @Super-intelligentShade It does work, but I don't want to accidentally call this function when I don't intend to do so.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in your code, it looks like a classic example of perfect forwarding, the one you show students when you try to explain this concept to them.

Comment: Seems fine, except I wouldn't use an abbreviated template. `decltype(val)` is usually a hint that `template<no_repetition<int> Int> void test(Int&& val) { ... std::forward<Int>... }` can be more readable.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen the thing that bugs me is that std::remove_cvref_t. I intuitively winged that concept but I am not sure how it works.

Comment: But `T1` and `T2` are not used anywhere. I don't understand what you are trying to do! It seems like you can perfectly forward an integer. But I don't see the need for `no_repetition`?

Comment: @suspiciously_large_carrot _"I intuitively winged that concept but I am not sure how it works."_ Which part do you not understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have oversimplified your question, but in your example the `test()` function is more restrictive than the `f(...)` functions. Specifically:

```cpp
double penetration = 69.;

f(69.);            // works
f(penetration);    // works, but f(int&&) is invoked !!

test(69.);         // fails
test(penetration); // fails
```

You can rewrite your function using universal references:

```cpp
void test5(auto&& val)
{
    f(std::forward<decltype(val)>(val));
}
```

which will behave the same way as the `f(...)` functions:

```
test5(69.); // works
test5(penetration); // works, but invokes f(int&&) !!
```

If you *do* want your `test()` function to have a hard constraint on `int`, then you have already come up with the best solution. In your comments you've mentioned that you don't understand how it works, so here is a quick explanation. If you have a concept, say:

```cpp
template<typename T, typename U>
concept Uref = std::same_as<std::remove_cvref_t<T>, U>;
```

you can write an abbreviated function-template, like you did:

```cpp
void test1(Uref<int> auto&& val)
{
    f(std::forward<decltype(val)>(val));
}
```

This is equivalent to:

```cpp
template< Uref<int> Int >
void test2(Int&& val)
{
    f(std::forward<Int>(val));
}
```

Notice that in the above example (as well as in the abbreviated function-template) you specify one less parameter in `Uref<int>` because the deduced type (`Int`) is implicitly substituted as the first parameter to `Uref`.

You could also re-write the above in a more verbose form:

```cpp
template<typename Int>
  requires Uref<Int, int>
void test3(Int&& val)
{
    f(std::forward<Int>(val));
}
```

Link to working example: https://godbolt.org/z/76hP3P5zz